# JSON attribute unreachable - “Cannot read property of undefined”

Tags: javascript, json

my json:

```
    {
  locale: "en",
  title: " Survey",
  focusFirstQuestionAutomatic: false,
  pages: [
   {
    name: "livingEnvironment",
    elements: [
     {
      type: "html",
      name: "navigationWarning",
      html: "warning"
     },
     {
      type: "html",
      name: "IntroEnvironment",
      html: "We will now ask you questions about your living environment ."
     },
     {
      type: "text",
      name: "numhousehold",
      width: "auto",
      title: "How many people (including yourself) lived in your household at the time of Hurricane Harvey? ",
      validators: [
       {
        type: "numeric",
        text: "Please enter a number between 1 and 99.",
        minValue: 1,
        maxValue: 99
       },
       {
        type: "expression",
        text: "you wrong here",
        expression: "{numhousehold} > {householdtype.children}"
       }
      ],
      inputType: "number"
     },
     {
      type: "multipletext",
      name: "householdtype",
      width: "auto",
      title: "Of these, how many (including yourself) were:",
      items: [
       {
        name: "children",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Children under 18 years old",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        name: "adults",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Adults between 18-59 years old",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
         }
        ]
       },
       {
        name: "seniors",
        inputType: "number",
        title: "Seniors (60+)",
        validators: [
         {
          type: "regex",
          text: "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
          regex: "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
        }]
            }
        ]
    }
]
}]
};
```

and my javascript is:

```
function serverValidateQuestion(survey, options) {
            console.log('Validation called');
            console.log(options);
            console.log(options.data.numhousehold);
            console.log(options.data.householdtype);
            console.log(options.data.householdtype.children);
```

so i can access "console.log(options.data.householdtype)" and it gives me the list of items in the in household type. However i am trying to access the "children" value input from householdtype. and when i write console.log(options.data.householdtype.children) it gives me "Cannot read property of undefined” error

Comment: I don't know, what object you are trying to access. The one you posted is neither valid json nor does is contain a property named `data` or `numhousehold` or any other of the mentioned you are trying to access in your code.

Comment: @derpirscher I only posted a partial json because it is a large file.  I am trying to access the object name "children." on the javascript "console.log(options.data.householdtype);" works but console.log(options.data.householdtype.children); doesn't work.

Comment: Post the portion of the data that is relevant to the question — we can’t debug what we can’t see.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but how on earth would an expression like `options.data.householdtype` work on the above json (assuming it's the `options` object)? There is no `data` property and no `householdtype` property. The above json seems more like a description of the resulting data structure, but not the data object itself.  Add the resulting output of `console.log(options)` to your question.

Comment: Based on this json, what would you expect from `options.data.householdtype` and `options.data.householdtype.children`?

Comment: @derpirscher it is a more of a survey where this is what i get  "
adults
:
"3"
children
:
"3"
disabled
:
"3"
pregnant
:
"3"
seniors
:
"3"
__proto__
:
Object" but I want access to the children value. This is from google console mode

Comment: So please tell me, where in that JSON object you gave us, can we find the information about `adults: 3` ??? Like I said above, what you gave us is some sort of a description of a survey, but not the resulting object. Show us the ***actual object*** resulting from this survey, because this is the one, you are accessing ...

Answer (score 0):

```js
var options = {
"locale": "en",
"title": " Survey",
"focusFirstQuestionAutomatic": false,
"pages": [{
 "name": "livingEnvironment",
 "elements": [{
   "type": "html",
   "name": "navigationWarning",
   "html": "warning"
  },
  {
   "type": "html",
   "name": "IntroEnvironment",
   "html": "We will now ask you questions about your living environment ."
  },
  {
   "type": "text",
   "name": "numhousehold",
   "width": "auto",
   "title": "How many people (including yourself) lived in your household at the time of Hurricane Harvey? ",
   "validators": [{
     "type": "numeric",
     "text": "Please enter a number between 1 and 99.",
     "minValue": 1,
     "maxValue": 99
    },
    {
     "type": "expression",
     "text": "you wrong here",
     "expression": "{numhousehold} > {householdtype.children}"
    }
   ],
   "inputType": "number"
  },
  {
   "type": "multipletext",
   "name": "householdtype",
   "width": "auto",
   "title": "Of these, how many (including yourself) were:",
   "items": [{
     "name": "children",
     "inputType": "number",
     "title": "Children under 18 years old",
     "validators": [{
      "type": "regex",
      "text": "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
      "regex": "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
     }]
    },
    {
     "name": "adults",
     "inputType": "number",
     "title": "Adults between 18-59 years old",
     "validators": [{
      "type": "regex",
      "text": "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
      "regex": "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
     }]
    },
    {
     "name": "seniors",
     "inputType": "number",
     "title": "Seniors (60+)",
     "validators": [{
      "type": "regex",
      "text": "One of the numbers below is out of range. Please enter 0, a positive number, or leave the box blank.",
      "regex": "^(\\s*|\\d+)$"
     }]
    }
   ]
  }
 ]
}]
};
   
   //var options = JSON.parse(str); //don't need if it's already JSON
   console.log('Validation called');       
   console.log(options.pages[0].elements[3].items[0].name); //accesses elements without a loop

//loop through all the nested elements to get the names
for(var page in options.pages) {    
    console.log("Page name: " + options.pages[page].name);         
    for(var element in options.pages[page].elements) {    
        console.log("Element name: " + options.pages[page].elements[element].name);
        for(var item in options.pages[page].elements[element].items) {    
            console.log("Item name: " + options.pages[page].elements[element].items[item].name);
        }    
    }
}
```

Here's my updated answer based on your new question:

Again, "children" is in the "items" array: there is no array under "householdtype". Also, if you have control over the json you receive, keeping it in the json format shown above (rather than a string) helps keep your code simpler, easier to debug, and you won't have to use `parse()`.

Comment: So i have editted the question to make the Json more clear can you please look again and see if you can help because this answer doesn't work

Comment: Maybe try accessing it with `options.pages[0].elements[3].items[0]['name']`?

Comment: You need 3 loops. Loop through the pages array, then the elements array, then the items array.

Comment: I included the 3 nested loops in my answer.

Comment: @VictorStoddard   its ok i was able to use the jquery to solve this issue sorry about that